# R6RS: Does the syntax expression form applied to the empty list return a wrapped syntax object?

Tags: scheme, racket, r6rs, chez-scheme

Consider the following expression in R6RS Scheme:

```
(syntax ())
```

When I type this expression into Racket, a (wrapped) syntax object is returned.  On the other hand, the same expression yields the (unwrapped) empty list in Chez Scheme.

I am wondering which system is in conformance with the R6RS (or whether both behaviors are allowed by the standard).  The relevant paragraph in R6RS is [Parsing input and producing output](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-13.html#node_sec_12.4).  There, it says:

> The output produced by syntax is wrapped or unwrapped according to the following rules
>   ... 
>   the copy of any portion of  not containing any pattern variables is a wrapped syntax object.

In `(syntax ())` the template does not contain any pattern variables, so it seems that the result should be a wrapped syntax object and that Racket is right.

On the other hand, R. Kent Dybvig, the author of Chez Scheme, is one of the inventors of the `syntax-case` system so one would expect Chez Scheme to follow the standard closely.

Comment: Just to clarify, Racket isn't an implementation of R6RS. It does contain an implementation of R6RS, though, and its R6RS implementation has the behavior you describe.

Comment: I used its R6RS mode. I am aware of the fact that Racket is much more than just R6RS. For example, the syntax form behaves differently in non-R6RS mode.